# Selecting child table's row upon selecting parent table's row using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and learning the things one by one.

I have a few main tables and nested tables inside those main tables. Each and every row of the parent table and child table has a check box for every row. Now, of and when the parent table's checkbox is selected, the check box of each and every row of child table/nested table should be selected.

I have used the following code to register the event:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('tr')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);


    });
});
```

But the above code is not working as expected. I am not able to traverse to the child table properly.

For illustration purposes, I have created a fiddle with one parent table and one child table.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

    $(this).siblings('tr')
      .find("input[type='checkbox']")
      .prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSAcheckBox" style="display: inline; left: 37px; position: relative;"><input id="SAcheckBox" name="SAcheckBox" type="checkbox" /> Select All</div>
<table id="parentTable" class="display dataTable no-footer" style="position: relative; top: 0px; width: 911px; table-layout: fixed;" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr style="height: 0px;" role="row">
      <th class="sorting_disabled" style="width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="chkbox" class="sorting_disabled" style="width: 51px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">Select
        <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Select</div>
      </th>
      <th id="media" class="sorting" style="border-left: 1px dashed #111111; text-align: left; width: 51px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">Media
        <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Media</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd shown" role="row" align="left">
      <td class="sorting_1"><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" align="center" /></td>
      <td class="details-control" style="width: 51px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 51px;">Phone</td>
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <table id="issuetable_12_13_2018_13_23_34" class="stripe nowrap" style="position: relative; margin: 5px 0 0 30px; cellspacing=0; border-collapse: collapse; align-text: left; top: 0px; width: 95%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; text-align: left; width: 333px;" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FAF6F2">Select</th>
              <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; text-align: left; width: 407px;" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FAF6F2">Priority</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr align="left">
              <td style="width: 333px;" nowrap="nowrap"><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" align="center" />&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width: 407px;" nowrap="nowrap">999</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSfddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU3FV/638/)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Current element is checkbox so it can't have `TR` as siblings use `$(this).closest('tr').find(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current element is checkbox so it can't have `TR` as siblings use `.closest()` to traverse up to parent `TR` element then perform the desired DOM traversal methods i.e. `.siblings()`, `.find()` to target the desired elements

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(...)
$(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').find(...)
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr')
      .find("input[type='checkbox']")
      .prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSAcheckBox" style="display: inline; left: 37px; position: relative;"><input id="SAcheckBox" name="SAcheckBox" type="checkbox" /> Select All</div>
<table id="parentTable" class="display dataTable no-footer" style="position: relative; top: 0px; width: 911px; table-layout: fixed;" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr style="height: 0px;" role="row">
      <th class="sorting_disabled" style="width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="chkbox" class="sorting_disabled" style="width: 51px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">Select
        <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Select</div>
      </th>
      <th id="media" class="sorting" style="border-left: 1px dashed #111111; text-align: left; width: 51px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;" colspan="1" rowspan="1">Media
        <div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">Media</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd shown" role="row" align="left">
      <td class="sorting_1"><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" align="center" /></td>
      <td class="details-control" style="width: 51px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 51px;">Phone</td>
      <td style="width: 90px;" colspan="9">
        <table id="issuetable_12_13_2018_13_23_34" class="stripe nowrap" style="position: relative; margin: 5px 0 0 30px; cellspacing=0; border-collapse: collapse; align-text: left; top: 0px; width: 95%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; text-align: left; width: 333px;" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FAF6F2">Select</th>
              <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; text-align: left; width: 407px;" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FAF6F2">Priority</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr align="left">
              <td style="width: 333px;" nowrap="nowrap"><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" align="center" />&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width: 407px;" nowrap="nowrap">999</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```